# iOS App using GoogleDrive SDK going to production

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am getting ready to launch an iOS App that uses the Google Drive SDK as well as the Dropbox SDK (and other cloud service SDKs). Dropbox has a limit of 100 users, until you apply for production status, where they approve your app and then remove this restriction.

However, as far as I can tell, Google doesn't require this. Am I correct? Is there anything I need to do with Google before submitting my App to the Apple App Store? Also, is anyone familiar with any caps or limits Google Drive may put on accounts using Google Drive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits are based around number of requests, rather than number of users.  You can see your default courtesy quota by looking at the details of the Drive API in the developer console: https://console.developers.google.com

At the top of the page there is a  link for Quota that shows the current limit, and has a link where you can request more if are approaching that limit.

Comment: There is also a configurable rate limit per user in that console. Default is 10/sec and is there to prevent individual users from consuming all your quota.